# Binding to GridView.Items.Count always return 0 in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, win-universal-app, uwp

I have a gridview in UWP and work fine

```
 <GridView x:Name="my_gridview" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

And have a textblock for show the count of CollectionItem

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=my_gridview, Path=Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Problem: the textblock always show 0 even we have many items in my gridview!

Comment: Did you try `<TextBlock Text="{Binding CollectionItem.Count}">`? Besides that, setting `Mode=TwoWay` on the ItemsSource binding doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better bind directly to the source collection:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CollectionItem.Count}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `ElementName` and `RelativeSource` (this one is bogus) at the same time, the latter probably overriding the former or causing a conflict error, check the Output window and there will be binding errors.

Comment: yes i try with clean this line RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} but dont work again

Comment: @nik: Check the output, it will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: please help me really i dont know what am i doing?

Comment: Search for "debugging binding errors", there are lots of articles on this.

Comment: Also if you don't know what you are doing [read up on it first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx) before cargo cult programming.

Comment: i started a new project that have just this gridview and this textblock the gridview show values but but textblok's value is 0! and in output have not any error!

Comment: If you have a minimal problem reproducing example you may want to post that, otherwise it's hard to guess where the problem would be. I just pointed out the obvious errors in the code you gave. There are usually many places where one can screw something like this up.

Comment: Also, yes, binding to the source collection as Clemens suggested is usually the best approach, still, the binding to the grid should work as well.

Comment: @H.B. Not sure if that's also true in UWP, although I can't test it right now.

Comment: @Clemens: Oh, you might be right, though it seems pretty basic.